# Netlink receive buffer alignment

Tags: c, linux, netlink

PVS-Studio, a static analyzer, reports that in `nh = (struct nlmsghdr *) buf`,

> The pointer 'buf' is cast to a more strictly aligned pointer type.

I think that the warning is correct.  Is this a serious problem?  The
code needs to be portable on various architectures.  How can I fix
this?

I know of some ways:

- allocate the buffer on the heap;
- use the [stdalign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types) features,
  but they’re not C99,
- the
  [cmsghdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) api uses an
  union to deal with the alignment, but I’m not sure if netlink does
  that.

Is there another option?

The code below is taken from the [netlink manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html).

```c
int len;
char buf[8192];     /* 8192 to avoid message truncation on
                       platforms with page size > 4096 */
struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof(buf) };
struct sockaddr_nl sa;
struct msghdr msg;
struct nlmsghdr *nh;

msg = { &sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
len = recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0);

for (nh = (struct nlmsghdr *) buf; NLMSG_OK (nh, len);
     nh = NLMSG_NEXT (nh, len)) {
     /* The end of multipart message */
     if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_DONE)
     return;

     if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR)
     /* Do some error handling */
     ...

     /* Continue with parsing payload */
     ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behavior because it violates both [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7):

"A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, **the behavior is undefined.**"  It's not possible to safely alias an actual array of `char` as something else.  Just Google "`SIGBUS` arm" or "`SIGBUS` sparc".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Should this be reported to the netlink project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't better to take a pointer of an allocated `struct nlmsghdr` instead of a `char buf[8192]`?

for example:

```
int len;
struct nlmsghdr buf;
struct iovec iov = { &buf, sizeof(buf) };
struct sockaddr_nl sa;
struct msghdr msg;
struct nlmsghdr *nh;

msg = { &sa, sizeof(sa), &iov, 1, NULL, 0, 0 };
len = recvmsg(fd, &msg, 0);

for (nh = &buf; NLMSG_OK (nh, len);
    nh = NLMSG_NEXT (nh, len)) {
    /* The end of multipart message */
    if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_DONE)
    return;

    if (nh->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR)
    /* Do some error handling */
    ...

    /* Continue with parsing payload */
    ...
}
```

Comment: *`sizeof(buf)` gives the size of the pointer not of the array.*  Not in the posted code as the full definition of the array is available.

Comment: I’m not sure, but I think that in this example only one nlmsghdr structure will be received, whereas with the `char` buffer, multiple messages can be appended.

Comment: This is not the only thing that it might be wrong. Also the length of the message in `NLMSG_OK (nh, len)` for example I think you need the `nh->nlmsg_len` instead. I don't have something ready for testing right now. Although if this it is only for 1 msg then just allocate an array of `struct nlmsghdr` like `struct nlmsghdr buf[256]`

Comment: No, the prototype is `int NLMSG_OK(struct nlmsghdr *nlh, int len);`. I’m going with `struct nlmsghdr buf[8192/sizeof(struct nlmsghdr)];`, and `sizeof(buf)` returns the size in bytes of `buf`, as expected.

Comment: The patch using my solution was accepted; see [ae10667](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/?id=ae10667d4891a592388f8dc63e1b01fed6a1b4bf).